# Refuses to get data

Tags: php

I am using this code to get the value of checked box in PHP but it doesn't work in the second code. The first one is just a list for testing. The second one will echo data from a database:

When applying the first code on the test list I will get the value of the box I checked but when applying it on the second part (one that gets data from database it returns Empty)

Get the checked boxes:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['DeleteCon']) )
    {
      if(!empty($_POST['lang']))
      {    
        foreach($_POST['lang'] as $value)
        {
            echo "value : ".$value.'<br/>';
        }
      }
      else
      {
        echo "value : Empty <br/>";
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Test list: it works on this section of the code:

```
<form method="post">

<?php
  echo "<span>Select languages</span><br/>
  <input type='checkbox' name='lang[]' value='PHP' class='table-row'> PHP <br/>
  <input type='checkbox' name='lang[]' value='JavaScript'> JavaScript <br/>
  <input type='checkbox' name='lang[]' value='jQuery'> jQuery <br/>
  <input type='checkbox' name='lang[]' value='Angular JS'> Angular JS <br/>"

   ?>
   </form>
```

But doesn't work on this one:

```
<form method="post">
 <?php    
    include('database.php');  
 
  $sql = "SELECT id, ContactID ,FirstName, LastName, Phone FROM Contact WHERE ID='1'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ( !empty($result->num_rows) && $result->num_rows > 0) { // ...
  // output data of each row
    echo "<form method='post'>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>
        <td id='delete'>
        <input type='checkbox' name='lang[]' value='PHP' class='table-row'>
        </td>
        <td>". $row["FirstName"]. "</td>
        <td>". $row["LastName"]. "</td>
        <td>". $row["Phone"] ."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</form>";
} else {
    echo "<tr>
    <td id='delete'>
     <input type='checkbox' id='row1' class='table-row'>
    </td>
    <td> 0 results </tr>";
}

$conn->close();
  
?>
</form>
```

Comment: This is useless `!empty($result->num_rows)`

Comment: just noticed that. i copied it somewhere and didn't change it

Comment: Where is your submit button?